# Замена namespace в asmx сервисе

Tags: c#, xml, soap, service, namespace

всем. Есть сервис Asmx с заданным namespace: http://Abc. Есть метод Method1(). В возвращаемом методе XML по-умолчанию формируется namespace   : http://Abc, а требутся указать другой namespace, например, http://BNM. Подскажите как можно это сделать.

Comment: Обычно на классы-модели навешаны атрибуты. Именно с помощью атрибутов можно задать неймспейс.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, мне для определенных методов надо менять этот атрибут namespace

Comment: [Applying Attributes to Return Values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-serialization-with-xml-web-services#applying-attributes-to-return-values)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ссылку можно?